# pygame.colliderect returning True despite not touching each other

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I was tinkering with PyGame, reading articles, and I came across this weird phenomenon. For some reason, pygame.colliderect returns `True` when the two sprites aren't touching.Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
running = True
spriteX = 100
spriteY = 100
spriteVY = 3
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.vel = (0, 0)
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((100, 200))
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rectangle = self.surf.get_rect()
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Platform, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((200, 10))
        self.surf.fill((142, 212, 25))
        self.rectangle = self.surf.get_rect()
on_ground = True
while running:
    platform_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    platform_group.add(Platform())
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]: spriteY -= 10
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]: spriteX += 10
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]: spriteX -= 10
    print((Platform().rectangle.colliderect(Sprite().rectangle)))
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if spriteX >= 300:
        spriteX = 300
    if spriteX <= 0:
        spriteX = 0
    if not on_ground:
        spriteY += spriteVY
        spriteVY -= 3
    screen.blit(Sprite().surf, ((spriteX, spriteY)))
    screen.blit(Platform().surf, ((50, 20)))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) has no position. Hence the position of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object which is returned by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is (0, 0).
Note you have to specify the position when the Surface is [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).

Specify the position by an keyword argument, when the the rectangle is get from the surface. 
Create instances of the objects before the main application loop (see [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)) and add them to a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). Each [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) should have the attributes `.rect` and `.image` which are used by the method [`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) of the group.
Get ride of the global variables `spriteX` and `spriteY` and use the `.rect` attribute of the sprites.

For instance:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
running = True
spriteVY = 3
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.vel = (0, 0)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 200))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((200, 10))
        self.image.fill((142, 212, 25))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

sprite = MySprite(100, 100)
platform = Platform(50, 20)
group = pygame.sprite.Group([sprite, platform])

on_ground = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]: sprite.rect.y -= 10
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]: sprite.rect.x += 10
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]: sprite.rect.x -= 10

    if platform.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect):
        print("hit")

    if sprite.rect.x >= 300:
        sprite.rect.x = 300
    if sprite.rect.x <= 0:
        sprite.rect.x = 0
    if not on_ground:
        sprite.rect.y += spriteVY
        spriteVY -= 3

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(24)
```